# Conditional statement not responding to results

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page there may be any number of UL's populated, with a maximum of 3 LI's in each. I have set this conditional statement up to handle the left margin, depending on how many LI's there may be. It logs the correct result, but it always applies the css as if the result was 1, even if the result is 2 or 3... I'm quite new to this so maybe I'm missing something obvious to a more experienced person. 
Each LI has a width and height of 40px and a background image. Text is indented so it doesn't show.

```
$("ul.links").each(function(){    
    var num = $(this).children().length;
    if (num == 1) {
        $('ul.links li:first-child').css('margin-left','125px');
    }
    else if (num == 2) {
        $('ul.links li:first-child').css('margin-left','96px');
    }
    else {
        $('ul.links li:first-child').css('margin-left','71px');
    }
    //console.log(num);
});

<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The code makes sense. Please show your HTML.

Comment: It works fine.. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PKypJ/ I just copied your code and pasted it. it worked ! Share your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$('ul.links li:first-child').css('margin-left','71px');
```

You are selecting ALL the ul.links again and applying the margin to ALL of them (or rather their first child). You need to apply it to just the one you are iterating over by using `this`.

Try this (no pun intended):

```
$("ul.links").each(function(){    
    var num = $(this).children().length;
    if (num == 1) {
        $(this).children().first().css('margin-left','125px');
    }
    else if (num == 2) {
        $(this).children().first().css('margin-left','96px');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children().first().css('margin-left','71px');
    }
    console.log(num);
});
```

See a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJxHH/2/).

As epascarello pointed out, for efficiency, you ought to cache you jQuery object instead of recreating it twice. So add:

```
var $elem = $(this);
```

And then whereever you have `$(this)`, you can replace it with `$elem`. The reason for doing this is every time you use `$(something)` you are creating a new jQuery object which has some overhead. For `$(this)` it's very small, but if you are using a complex selector, the overhead can be significant.

Also, as epascarello did, you can save a few bytes in your source code by creating a variable for the margin and then applying it at the end of the conditional block. In addition, this does makes it a little easier if you, for example, decide to change the selector (maybe you decide to apply it to the second child instead of the first) or change the property you want to fiddle with.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figured it was something to do with "this". Trying to get that in my head!!

Comment: You could have least improved the code so it is not copy paste happy. Yikes!

Comment: @epascarello: I pointed out where the problem was and gave a solution. I didn't claim it was perfect or the most efficient. Optimizing the code to the point where the OP doesn't even recognize it doesn't really help the OP. I would at least cache the jQuery object, but that wasn't the question. If the code only runs once when the page loads, it likely makes very little difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work since you are working off all of the uls and not the current one. Below is one way of working wit the current url and each and doing it without copying and pasting the same line multiple times. Reason why having the same exact line copy and pasted 3 times means that in the future you need to change it, you have to update in THREE places instead of ONE.

```
$("ul.links").each(function(){
    var currentUL = $(this),
        num = currentUL.children().length,
        margin;  //use a variable instead of pasting the same jq line over and over
    switch(num){  //switch is cleaner
        case 1 : 
            margin=125;
            break;
        case 2 : 
            margin=96;
            break;
        default : 
            margin=71;
            break;
    }
    currentUL  //Work off the current ul
        .find(">li:first-child")  //select the first li
            .css("margin-left",margin + "px");   
});
```

Comment: You could have at least explained what the OP did wrong. Yikes!

Comment: Also, you are still creating `$(this)` twice, which is unnecessary.